# Lollipop - ImageView fail to load image - app crash

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my app, it fails to start if I specify the source of the image. Logcat indicates fail just at loading the XML file at line 0. I am trying to emulate to API22(Android 5.1 - lollipop) as my device is a OnePlus One - note it fails on both of them (phone and emulator). BUT if I try to emulate on API24(Android 7.0) works just fine.

If I remove the line, it starts, but of course it does not display the image:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/glass_bottle"
```

Any help is much appreciated.[image]

---

Edit 1: added trace log:

```
11-29 20:12:40.475 5765-5765/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-29 20:12:40.493 5765-5773/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-29 20:12:40.493 5765-5773/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-29 20:12:40.544 5765-5765/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-29 20:12:40.583 5765-5765/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-29 20:12:40.672 5765-5765/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060056 (t=5 e=86) (error -75)
11-29 20:12:40.672 5765-5765/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060056 (t=5 e=86) (error -75)
11-29 20:12:40.673 5765-5765/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-29 20:12:40.673 5765-5765/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: org.org.chemfun, PID: 5765
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.org.chemfun/org.org.chemfun.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                     at org.org.chemfun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060056
                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                     at org.org.chemfun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

---

Edit 2: if I try to use the **ic_launcher** for the source (default icon image from Android) it starts the app fine; my images are all PNG and are placed in the **drawable** package

Comment: If you app is crashing, how about posting the crash details? It'd really help.

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: xml is fine show error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, what I have been using -> Copy - Paste PNG images in drawable was not enough (even if all the references were alright etc)

The way to solve this was adding one by one -> RightClick on app -> new -> Image asset -> apply tweaks -> reference in your code from mipmap package

quite annoying and involved for every singe image.. I just want to use a damn PNG image, really?